# looping thru multidimentional array and getting value of keys

Tags: php, arrays

how can i get all latitude and longitude of below multi dimensional array and store it in separate array.

```
Array
(
    [Beauty & Wellness] => Array
        (
            [kategorie_icon_0] => abc
            [kategorie_icon_1] => cde
            [partnerlist] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39552
                            [latitude] => 49.773109
                            [longitude] => 8.641460
                        )   
                     [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39550
                            [latitude] => 49.871452
                            [longitude] => 8.643979
                        )
                )       
        )
    [fashion] => Array
        (
            [kategorie_icon_0] => abc
            [kategorie_icon_1] => cde
            [partnerlist] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39552
                            [latitude] => 49.773109
                            [longitude] => 8.641460
                        )   
                     [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39550
                            [latitude] => 49.871452
                            [longitude] => 8.643979
                        )
                )       
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Initiate new array to store coords
$latlongs = array();

//Loop through your array
foreach($yourArray as $k=>$v){
      // Loop through the partnerlist to extract lat/lon
      // Append to your coord array, and preserve the industry key
      // So that you know which lat/lons came from where
      foreach($v['partnerlist'] as $a){
         $latlongs[$k][] = array("latitude"=>$a['latitude'],"longitude"=>$a['longitude'];
      }
}
```

This will preserve the key, so that you can group all your coords together by their original category.

If you dont care about that and purely want just the lat/long, then simply do...

```
foreach($yourArray as $v){
      foreach($v['partnerlist'] as $a){
         $latlongs[] = array("latitude"=>$a['latitude'],"longitude"=>$a['longitude'];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$coords = array();

foreach ($master_array as $array)
{
    foreach ($array['partnerlsit'] as $partner)
    {
        $coords []= array('lat' => $partner['latitude'], 'lng' => $partner['longitude']);

    } 
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same as my answer....but will only store all the latitudes and longitudes with no reference to their original industry.  My answer preserves the original reference key